# Bootstrap sidebar responsive link

Tags: jsp

I want to show customerAdd.jsp ,customerList and customerDelete when I click their own links . I devised their links in the left bar . How do I devise responsive link.

I appreciate you if you help me solve it out.

Here is the code below.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>CRUD</title>

<!-- CSS Files -->
<link href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">

<!-- JS Files -->
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">

            <div class="list-group">
            <a href="views/customerAdd.jsp" class="list-group-item"> add </a> 
            <a href="views/customerList.jsp" class="list-group-item"> list</a> 
            <a href="views/customerDelete.jsp"class="list-group-item">delete</a> 
            <a href="#"class="list-group-item"> Update</a>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">

            <!--  Showing customerAdd , customerList and customerDelete -->
            <jsp:include page="views/customerAdd.jsp"></jsp:include>


        </div>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use templating in jsp or <jsp:include page="${page}"></jsp:include> page will change from backend

Comment: <jsp:include page="${customerAdd.jsp}"></jsp:include> or <jsp:include page="${views/customerAdd.jsp}"></jsp:include> isn't work.  Where do I put the code there. Thks